# Is there any way to allow moving a container that has a borrowed element but not dropping it?

Tags: collections, rust, borrow-checker

I have this container:

```rust
use std::ptr::NonNull;

struct Container {
    data: NonNull<u8>,
}

impl Container {
    fn new() -> Container {
        todo!()
    }
    fn borrow_some_heap_data<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a u8 {
        todo!()
    }
    fn borrow_some_heap_data_mut<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut u8 {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Drop for Container {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let container = Container::new();
    let data = container.borrow_some_heap_data(); // or mut

    {
        let container = container; // move

        // This is safe because the move is a memcpy and the heap data doesn't change.
        println!("{}", *data);
    }

    // This is not safe because the container has been dropped
    // println!("{}", *data);
}
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `container` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:30:25
   |
27 |     let data = container.borrow_some_heap_data(); // or mut
   |                --------- borrow of `container` occurs here
...
30 |         let container = container; // move
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^ move out of `container` occurs here
...
33 |         println!("{}", *data);
   |                        ----- borrow later used here
```

Moving the container is safe even if there are references. Dropping it, however, is not safe. Is there any way to express this in Rust, to allow moves but not `drop`s?

`data` is never deallocated until the struct is dropped.

Comment: `std::mem::drop` works by moving the value, too. It's impossible to distinguish `let container = container` and `drop(container)`, since both are moves.

Comment: I suppose so, but `std::mem::drop` moves and drops when it goes out of scope. If I dropped `container` by shadowing it in a new scope, reading `data`, then exiting the scope, the second `println` would still be unsafe.

Comment: Heads up, don't put EDIT markers into your question. It's better to just edit it without drawing attention to the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way of doing this in safe Rust; the compiler is not intelligent enough / there's no syntax to distinguish the container's lifetime from the lifetimes of the elements.

From [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423):

> There is a special case where the lifetime tracking is overzealous:
> when you have something placed on the heap. This occurs when you use a
> `Box<T>`, for example. In this case, the structure that is moved
> contains a pointer into the heap. The pointed-at value will remain
> stable, but the address of the pointer itself will move. In practice,
> this doesn't matter, as you always follow the pointer.